# Google Analytics API: "Error 403 - User does not have sufficient permissions for this web property."

Tags: authentication, google-analytics, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I've been trying to link a google ads and google analytics account through google analytics API. However, I always get the following error:

```
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/xxxxxxxxx/webproperties/UA-xxxxxxxxx-1/entityAdWordsLinks?alt=json returned "User does not have sufficient permissions for this web property.">
```

I properly gave permissions to my service account email (at account level). Moreover, for all other methods, authentification has been successful and without any problem. For example, I was able to get all the data about links and even remove some of them which were manually added. 
You can see the methods here on the link:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webPropertyAdWordsLinks

Before running the following lines of code, I implemented the code which you can find on the following link (python - quickstart for service accounts):
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/quickstart/service-py

```
analytics = get_service(
            api_name='analytics',
            api_version='v3',
            scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit'],
            key_file_location='my_service_account_things.json')

analytics.management().webPropertyAdWordsLinks().insert(
      accountId='XXXXXXXXXXXX',
      webPropertyId='UA-XXXXXXXXXXXX-1',
      body={"adWordsAccounts": [{"customerId": "xxx-yyy-zzzz"}],"name": "Name of the link"}).execute()
```

It is important to point out that when I use "Try this API", the option provided at the documentation webpage (see the screenshot), with exactly the same data I am able to link my google ads and analytics accounts. 
[Screenshot of try this API option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxrFB.png)

Any ideas?